# Browser-specific layout for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, safari, compatibility

I'm currently building a site, which looks very well in Safari, but many elements are out of place in other browsers (IE, Chrome (Chromium, Canary, regular), Firefox). I can fix the issue in those three browsers by putting a `<p>` tag instead of `<br />` between the two elements, but then they aren't flush, as in my initial design, into which I've put quite a lot of work. I can probably put conditional comments for IE, but what of Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a layout problem, which CSS was designed to solve.

Try using a CSS reset to start with (so you can get some sort of predictable behavior across browsers), and go from there.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. If you want to see what I'm talking about, visit the site. http://goo.gl/AiEf1
Oddly enough, Netscape supports the site better than any other browser. Safari's good too, but Chrome, Chromium, Canary, Firefox and most other browsers I've tried mess up the position of the menu bar.